# Change Toggle Columns icon to text

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using Angular 7 and VMWare's [Clarity Datagrid](https://clarity.design/documentation/datagrid/hide-show). Is there a way to change the Show/Hide columns button in the Datagrids footer to say "Show/Hide Columns" instead of showing a Column icon?

[image: Show/Hide Columns Button]

I noticed that I can change Title and Button text in the dialog, once I click on the icon using the following code, but, I am not sure how to change the column icon to text.

```
<clr-dg-column-toggle>
  <clr-dg-column-toggle-title>Show Columns</clr-dg-column-toggle-title>
  <clr-dg-column-toggle-button>Select All</clr-dg-column-toggle-button>
</clr-dg-column-toggle>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, the icon is internal to the datagrid. Theoretically you could overload the directive and rewrite the content yourself with a custom directive, which I don't have time to try and implement.

Comment: An alternative solution is to create a button called "Show/Hide Columns" outside the Datagrid, but have it trigger the action on the button in the footer. I can later hide the   icon in the footer through CSS. I am not sure how to trigger the click using an external button though.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this, by adding a button external to the Datagrid and trigger the click on the button in the footer:

**In HTML:**

```
<button (click)="showHideColumns();">Show/Hide Columns</button>
```

**In Component TypeScript:**

```
showHideColumns()
{
  var el = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector(".column-switch-wrapper").firstElementChild;
  el.click();
}
```